# How to continue execute code after Response.End()

Tags: c#, asp.net

As long as the page is still executing codes, the client's internet browser will show the loading sign. I wish that the client internet browser will stop showing loading sign.

Therefore, I tried to execute the following:

```
Response.End();
```

But the page stops there and will not continue to execute remaining codes. What is correct way to do this?

Comment: From what assembly `Response` comes from?

Comment: Split some of the page load tasks so that they can be loaded via ajax?

Comment: what "remaining codes" did not execute? and what makes you think they didn't execute? `Response.End()` does indeed finish the actual *response*, but AFAIK any code immediately after the `Response.End()` should still run - it doesn't throw or kill the thread, IIRC. Obviously: if you didn't send anything to the client before you killed the response, the *client* won't see anything ... but ... yeah, you killed the response, so : not much you can do there...

Comment: @OlegI `HttpContext.Current.Response.End();`

Comment: @Neil Yupe, using ajax solves the problem. Thanks for the tips. You may re-post as answer. I'll vote it up and select it as "Answered"

Comment: @MarcGravell I have tried that, `Response.End()` will kill the thread and skip remaining codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split some of the page load tasks so that they can be loaded via ajax.